# como faço para fazer requisições get e post através de curl?

Tags: php, libcurl

tenho esta classe com os seguintes métodos :

```
 public function __construct($url,$followlocation = true,$timeOut = 30,$maxRedirecs = 4,$binaryTransfer = false,$includeHeader = false,$noBody = false) 
 { 
    //setando valores nas variáveis  
     $this->_url = $url; 
     $this->_followlocation = $followlocation; 
     $this->_timeout = $timeOut; 
     $this->_maxRedirects = $maxRedirecs; 
     $this->_noBody = $noBody; 
     $this->_includeHeader = $includeHeader; 
     $this->_binaryTransfer = $binaryTransfer; 
     $this->_cookieFileLocation = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'; 
 } 


public function buildCurl($url = 'nul') 
{ 
    if($url != 'nul'){ 
      $this->_url = $url; 
    } 

     $s = curl_init(); 

     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,$this->_url); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:')); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$this->_timeout); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,$this->_maxRedirects); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,$this->_followlocation); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->_cookieFileLocation); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->_cookieFileLocation); 

     if($this->authentication == 1){ 
       curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->auth_name.':'.$this->auth_pass); 
     } 
     if($this->_post) 
     { 
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true); 
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->_postFields); 

     } 

     if($this->_includeHeader) 
     { 
           curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HEADER,true); 
     } 

     if($this->_noBody) 
     { 
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true); 
     } 
     /* 
     if($this->_binary) 
     { 
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true); 
     } 
     */ 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->_useragent); 
     curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_REFERER,$this->_referer); 

     $this->_webpage = curl_exec($s); 
     $this->_status = curl_getinfo($s,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 

     curl_close($s); 

     } 

     public function getResponse($url)
     { 
       $this->buildCurl($url);

       return $this->_webpage; 
     }
```

e aqui a chamada do método em outro arquivo no meu controller .

```
     public function cURL($id)
     {
       $_url = "https://receitacpf.cf/api/cpf/$id";

       $curl = new Curl($_url);

       return $curl->getResponse($_url);
     }
```

gostaria de saber o por que não está dando nenhum erro mais tambem não está trazendo nada , to quebrando a cabeça nisso

Comment: Você está apenas retornando para algum lugar a *response*, e não printando-a. Execute um `print_r()` ou `var_dump()` ou `var_export()` no retorno dessa função e nos mostre o que aparece.

Comment: dei um var_dump() e pelo menos já retorno algo assim : string(3309) " "

Comment: Se você acessar essa API e colocar seu CPF `https://receitacpf.cf/api/cpf/` vc verá que o total de caracteres que vai ter na página é 3309.

Comment: Faça o teste em http://onlinecurl.com/. Coloque a url da api + um cpf.

Comment: Explicando o que está acontecendo... Ao executar `echo` ou `var_dump()` você verá tudo em branco, porém, aperte com o botão direito do mouse em qualquer lugar da tela em branco e vá em `Exibir o código fonte da página`. Então você verá que o resultado do seu `cURL` está ali.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda , mais como eu teria que fazer para trazer por exemplo  resultado de outra forma ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$url='https://receitacpf.cf/api/cpf/NUMERODOCPF';

$ch = curl_init($url);

$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';
$request_headers[] = 'Client: Apple';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers); /* Moved this line here */

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'insertedmycookiehere');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.99 Safari/535.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Comment: obrigadão pela ajuda cara

Comment: @PedroAmorim De nada :]

Comment: e nesse code caso eu não queira trazer a mensagem zipada , caso eu queira tazer realmente a mensagem como eu faria eu omiti esta linha $request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'; e deu erro

Comment: Você pode escolher qual encoding deseja utilizar. Dá uma lida [neste link!](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html)

Comment: cara não saquei ainda se eu colocoar  > 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'; e substituir por nada ou por null como fala no artigo do link da erro mano

Comment: e eu só queria trazer a mensagem limpa sem ser criptografada de nenhuma forma @Godfrey the King